# Is it correct to say “the number of X ... totaled/amounted to Y”?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage, verbs

I bumped into this sentence in IELTS writing task 1:

> **Male students** studying philosophy at University of Cambridge in 2001 **numbered** 50

My question: Can I use "amounted to" and "totaled" instead of "numbered" because I notice that I can write:

> **The number of male students** studying philosophy at University of Cambridge in 2001
> **totaled/amounted to 50**

Comment: It's a somewhat bizarre utterance anyway (normal Anglophones would more likely say something like ***There were 50** male students studying philosophy at...* or just ***50 men studied...***), so it's not obvious to me that switching between ***amounted to, totaled,*** and ***numbered*** makes it any more or less "natural". They're all syntactically valid, and will be equally well understood.

Comment: The lack of a definite article before 'University of Cambridge' here makes me wonder whether this is a new vogue, or whether example questions aren't vetted adequately for standardness. @FF seems to have similar doubts. // I'd say 'total[l]ed' would be reasonable iff there were a prior discussion (looking at subsets, say) but 'amounted to' sounds at best clunky. Your last suggestion is also sub-optimal, unnaturally tautological; why not 'was'?